# Subtotal on filtered rows

Tags: excel

I have a question concerning Excel's Subtotal function. More specifically in combination with filter (to show/hide rows) AND data grouping. I'm adding in attachment a mockup file containing the same structure as my real file.

In short I want to use subtotal to make the sum for each order - containing a number of lines with quantities/cost. Then I want to use subtotal again to make the total sum of the entire column (which includes both the lines and orders so would result in twice the amount if using "SUM" function).
So far, so good. This part works, also in combination with the data groups. I can collapse/expand single data group of all groups at once.

The problem is when I start using filters as well, all rows that are hidden by the data grouping are not summed anymore. Let me explain with a couple of screenshots:

[Without any filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAlut.png)
=> Green is a subtotal of one order, blue a subtotal of another order. Red is the total sum, including the 3rd order which is just a number (not a subtotal). All these values are correct.

[Same info but with all data grouping collapsed to level 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35icf.png)
=> As you can see the values for the subtotal and grand total are the same, as it should be.

[Using filter to hide 'Order 3'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xZqK.png)
=> Now using the filter I am hiding order 3 because it hasn't been approved yet. The subtotal and grand total show all information from orders 1 and 2 which is perfect.

[Same info but with all data grouping collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXwkd.png)
=> This is the same as picture 2 but with the only difference that order 3 has been hidden. However because of the activation of a filter the subtotals for orders 1 and 2 are no longer being calculated.

In short, I want to have the 4th picture (with filtering used and data grouping/manual hide used) but WITH the subtotals being calculated.

Anyone have any idea how to achieve this with standard Excel functionality?

Comment: Use sumif() or sumifs() and control the constraints.

Comment: I think it would be easier use Pivot Tables to handle this, but you would need to change a little bit your data source

Comment: @SolarMike, that would not work in my real file. I now use this simple column "Hide/Show" but in reality the filtering can be done on so many other columns

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, unfortunately not an option. The project is about halfway, this file format is fixed. I can't even insert columns or anything.